# Can't take a label from a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, label

i'm trying to compare a value from an HTML label, but can't parser it.

from this JS

```
document.getElementById ("00NE0000001BprW_chkbox");
```

i get this HTML

```
img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="00NE0000001BprW_chkbox" title="Not Checked"
```

I need to compare with the title that if is "Checked", it's ok.
How can i compare with the title label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( document.getElementById('obscenely-long-id').title === "Checked")
```

That's all you need. Optionally, convert it to lower case and compare it against `"checked"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("00NE0000001BprW_chkbox").title == "Checked") {
    // title matches
}
```

Comment: @FerminBrochado: Great that this answer helped you. The other answers should work as well. Consider selecting one of them as accepted answer. This is a good way to say thank you and to encourage people to answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to visualize your output with some kind of console.
the line

```
document.getElementById ("00NE0000001BprW_chkbox");
```

gives you a DOM object. In your case it is an IMG element.

If you want to compare the title attribute with something, you should use the "title" property of this DOM object :

```
var myImg = document.getElementById ("00NE0000001BprW_chkbox");
alert(myImg.title));
```

so use

```
if( myImg.title === "Checked") {
```

for example

you can find other properties of the DOM elements [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml).